# Visualization install problem in Pydroid 3

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, pydroid

I am a beginner at python. I don't have any pc where i can code so i use my android mobile phone to write program.

I wanted to created a game something like flappy bird for that i need a module called "Visualization".

But i can't install that. Whenever i try to install "visualization" the result is:

```
> Looking in indexes: http:// repo.local
```

> Collecting visualization
> Using cached visualization-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
>
> Collecting autolab-core Using cached autolab_core-0.0.14-py3-none anywhl (73 kB)
>
> Collecting pyrender Using cached pyrender-0.1.43-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
>
> Collecting imageio Using cached imageio-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
>
> Collecting autolab-perception Using cached autolab_perception-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
>
> Collecting trimesh[easy] Using cached trimesh-3.8.12-py3-none-any.whl (626 kB)
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib<=2.2.0 (from visualization) (from versions: 3.2.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib<=2.2.0 (from visualization)

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Add it to the question (quoted or in a code block).

Comment: It this okay now?